# Javascript order total for coffee cant get function to work. PLEASE ASSIST

Tags: javascript, html, function

Alright so heres the task for the javascript part of my homework.

The Javascript function will:

1. Take three parameters: a name, the drink type, and the number of extra shots
2. Check to make sure a name was given and alert the user if there’s no name
3. Calculate the drink price based on the type ordered
4. Add additional costs based on the number of extra shots ordered
5. Alert the user when the drink total has been calculated. It will inform the user of the drink ordered, number of extra shots, and the total cost of the order.

Here’s information you’ll need for your programming:

1. Available drinks and prices a. Latte = $3.00 b. Americano = $2.00 c. Cappuccino = $2.50 d. Drip coffee = $1.50
2. Extra espresso shots are $.50 each a. Only up to 4 extra shots can be ordered

And heres my code, I cant get the javascript part I've been trying for hours now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function first(drink, shots, customer) { 
    var x = customer.value; 
    if (x == '' || x == 'null') { 
        alert("Yo enter a name."); 
    }
    else { 
        if (drink == "0") { 
            price = 3; 
        } else if (drink == "1") { 
            price = 2; 
        } else if (drink == "2") { 
            price = 2.50; 
        } else { 
            price = 1.50; 
        } 
        if(shots > 0) { 
            Price= price + (shots * 0.5) 
        } else { 
            alert ("Thank you"); 
        } 
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<h1>Javascript calculating Function: Calculate the cost of a coffee drinks using Javascript.</h1>
<p>What would you like to order?</p>

<select id="drink">

    <option value="0" id="0">Latte</option>
    <option value="1" id="1">Americano</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">Cappuccino</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">Drip Coffee</option>

</select>

<br>
<br>

<select id="shots">

    <option value="0" id="0">No Extra</option>
    <option value="1" id="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" id="4">4</option>

</select>

<br>
<br>

<p>Enter name here:</p>

<input id="customer" value="customer" type="text"/>

<br>

 <br>

    <button onclick="first(drink, shots, customer)">Complete Order</button>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any help is appreciated thank you in advance!

Comment: You're not setting `drink`, `shots`, and `customer` before calling the function. You need to get them from the values of the `<select>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the arguments to `first()` from the input fields.

```
<button onclick="first(document.getElementById('drink').value, document.getElementById('shots').value, document.getElementById('customer'))">Complete Order</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will fix this and see where I'm at.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<h1>Javascript calculating Function: Calculate the cost of a coffee drinks using Javascript.</h1>
```

What would you like to order?

```
<option value="0" id="0">Latte</option>
<option value="1" id="1">Americano</option>
<option value="2" id="2">Cappuccino</option>
<option value="3" id="3">Drip Coffee</option>
```

```
<option value="0" id="0">No Extra</option>
<option value="1" id="1">1</option>
<option value="2" id="2">2</option>
<option value="3" id="3">3</option>
<option value="4" id="4">4</option>
```

Enter name here:

```
<button id='submit'>Complete Order</button>
<script>
$("#submit").click(function () 
{
    var drink = $("#drink").val();
    var shots = $("#shots").val();
    var customer = $("#customer").val();
    
    var x = customer; 
    if (x == '' || x == 'null') 
    { 
        alert("Yo enter a name."); 
    }
   else 
   { 
       if (drink == "0") { price = 3; } 
       else if (drink == "1") { price = 2; } 
       else if (drink == "2") { price = 2.50; } 
       else { price = 1.50; } 
       if(shots > 0) 
       {
           price= price + (shots * 0.5) 
       } 
       alert ("Your Order Total is : "+price+" \nThank you"); 
       
   }
});
</script>
```